# Create own qty attribute in magento

Tags: magento, attributes

I have one problem. There is 4 sites on magento.
They are for different countries. 
And attribute qty is global. As I know that I can`t change this parameter. I so decided to create own attribute 'shop_gty', which I can change on site level.
How to make magento work with this attribute.
And after ordering , value of count products will change.